# Gradient only on one section

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my previous post I asked how I'd get the gradient set up. Now the problem is that the gradient "spreads" out. Here's What I'm using

```
function generateCSSGradient(colours) {
var l = colours.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) colours[i] = colours[i].join(" ");
return "linear-gradient( to right, "+colours.join(", ")+")";
}

var cols = [
["red","0%"],
["red","40%"],
["yellow","40%"], 
["yellow","60%"],
["green","60%"],
["green","80%"]
];
yourElement.style.background = generateCSSGradient(cols);
```

With [this](http://colourity.github.io). What I want to do is say you fill in one input. And the bar goes to 33%, then that could be a red color. Then the next would be a blue and so fourth. Not like [this](http://jsbin.com/mivaxoyo/1). Any ideas? I'd also avoid using `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want it like [this](http://jsbin.com/mivaxoyo/10/) ...  See the [source code](http://jsbin.com/mivaxoyo/10/edit?html,css,js,output)

#### HTML

I'v edited the **HTML** code and added another **div** called `colors` inside the **div** `top` ...

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="colors"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

Also I edited the **CSS** of `.top` and added to it `overflow:hidden;` and create `.colors` style

```
.top{
    /*background: #009dff;*/
    background:linear-gradient(to right,#009dff 0,#00c8ff 100%);
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1031;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:4px;
    transition:all 1s;
    width:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.colors{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
}
```

#### JavsScript

Then edited the **JavaScript** and made the **CSSGradient** to `colors` not `top` , and let the JavaScript set the **width** of `colors` to fit the **window width** , and changed the colors percentage..

```
document.querySelector(".colors").style.background = generateCSSGradient(cols);

var window_width = window.innerWidth + "px";
document.querySelector(".colors").style.width = window_width;

var cols = [
    ["red","0%"],
    ["red","33.3%"],
    ["yellow","33.3%"],
    ["yellow","66.6%"],
    ["green","66.6%"],
    ["green","100%"]
];
```

Hope this will help you ...

---

## Update

if you want to change the color of the bar like [this](http://jsbin.com/mivaxoyo/9/) , See the [source code](http://jsbin.com/mivaxoyo/9/edit?html,css,js,output) ...

just edit the **JavaScript** to be like this

```
function cback(e) {
    var t = [];
    for (var n = inputs.length; n--;) {
        if (!inputs[n].value.length) t.push(inputs[n]);
    }
    var r = t.length;
    var i = inputs.length;
    var s = document.querySelectorAll(".top");
    for (var o = s.length; o--;) {
        s[o].style.width = 100 - r / i * 100 + "%";
        s[o].style.background = cols[i-r-1];
    }
}
var forms = document.querySelectorAll(".form"),
    inputs = [];
for (var i = forms.length; i--;) {
    var els = forms[i].querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select");
    for (var j = els.length; j--;) {
        if (els[j].type != "button" && els[j].type != "submit") {
            inputs.push(els[j]);
            els[j].addEventListener("input", cback, false);
        }
    }
}

var cols = ["red","yellow","green"];
```

Comment: Once again mate. Read the full post please. The last sentence specifically. And its not what I wanted really.

Comment: Something like that. But not the whole bar changes color, rather only the section.

Comment: @Idris i'm sorry, I didn't understand what you exactly mean, which section do you mean??

Comment: Yeah thats what it is.